# SUPEE-8788 installation trouble for magento v1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-8788

My magento website is on a centos server. I am accessing the server via ssh from my mac osx terminal.

Below are the steps that I have taken:

1- I already had SUPEE-1533 installed, so I have reverted this first.

2- As other forums have suggested, I have installed SUPEE-3941.

3- I have downloaded and zipped the SUPEE-8788 patch, uploaded to site via ftp then unzipped the patch via terminal and then attempted to install patch however it didn't work.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Below is the terminal log:

```
************************** [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.7.0.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-32-17.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 373 (offset -19 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #7 succeeded at 506 (offset -5 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 136 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 158 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 189 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 198 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 208 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #6 FAILED at 272.
Hunk #7 succeeded at 400 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 420 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 432 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 447 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 471 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 496 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 517 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #14 succeeded at 536 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #15 succeeded at 578 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #16 succeeded at 594 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #17 succeeded at 625 with fuzz 2 (offset -24 lines).
Hunk #18 succeeded at 644 (offset -23 lines).
Hunk #19 FAILED at 705.
Hunk #20 succeeded at 708 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #21 succeeded at 741 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #22 succeeded at 764 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #23 succeeded at 785 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #24 succeeded at 863 with fuzz 2 (offset -21 lines).
2 out of 24 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/customer/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
can't find file to patch at input line 7570
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7582
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|index caa979e..cd37804 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7598
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|index d2a4937..c6c0221 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
************************** [~/public_html]#
```